# advise on adding events in the object constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need an advice on adding event (mouse click for that matter) in the class constructor.

I've got a array of images that i get from Flickr and that can be change and i want to add to them a click event.

I really had a problem with that so i made a class image and add the event in the constructor so i wont need to search what control i clicked on the page every time i clicked him.

Here is a sample of the constructor:

```
 public FlickerImages(string url, string title, string desc,  System.Web.UI.Page page,ImageButton image)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.title = title;
    this.descreption = desc;
    this.image = image;

    image.Click += this.onImageClick; //--> the event
    //image is a ImageButton object

    this.page = page;


}
```

I want to know if that is a good practice or should i always add events outside the objects class'?

(sorry for my English)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it was only a small test and i want to see result fast so i referenced the page and you the page.Response.Write("") method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into this similar question:

[Is it poor form for a C# class to subscribe to its own published events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031157/is-it-poor-form-for-a-c-sharp-class-to-subscribe-to-its-own-published-events)

But apart from that, why do you store the reference to the page in the image class? You should also ensure that these objects are recreated on every postback.

I would suggest to use [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) instead and add appropriate properties and events.

Answer (score 2):

You should also have a `-=`, maybe you could make your class IDisposable and unreference the event in the `.Dispose()` method.

Comment: do you mean in a good idea to add events in the class's, and just make sure i have the possiblty to unsubscribe the event inside the class?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you... it is a different approach but could help

http://blog.majcica.com/2011/12/01/a-simple-asp-net-flickr-application-part-2/