# MVVM ViewModel Cascading Properties

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, reactiveui

I have a view model with properties A, B, C, and D. Where D is the sum of A, B, and C. So whenever any of those changes, I want D to be updated. I know I can do it by watching for PropertyChanged events on A, B, C and then setting the value for D, like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged;
}

private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Track changes to update sum
    if (e.PropertyName == "A" || e.PropertyName == "B" || e.PropertyName == "C")
    {
        D = A + B + C;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is more elegant or more automated that exists?

Updating this to add an example of the property. I'm using a framework that encapsulates the logic for: is different and raising the property changed event.

```
    private int _A;
    public int A
    {
        get { return _A; }
        set { RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _A, value); }
    }
```

Update #2: Does anyone have an example of how this might be implemented using ReactiveUI?

Comment: I think you should consider https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs

Comment: Reactive crossed my mind. Do you have any example code @jmelosegui?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than do the actual math in your `ViewModelPropertyChanged` I would do something like

```
private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Track changes to update sum
    if (e.PropertyName == "A" || e.PropertyName == "B" || e.PropertyName == "C")
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("D");
    }
}
```

And then do the math in the property itself

```
public int D
{
    get
    {
        return A + B + C;
    }
}
```

Or you could do this **(which is the one I prefer see the comments below)**

```
public int A
{
    get { return a; }
    set
    {
        if (value == a) return;
        a = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("A");
        OnPropertyChanged("D");
    }
}

public int B
{
    get { return b; }
    set
    {
        if (value == b) return;
        b = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("B");
        OnPropertyChanged("D");
    }
}
```

and so on

then again

```
public int D
{
    get
    {
        return A + B + C;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more elegant that putting the extra code in the set of the other properties. +1

Comment: the down side is that the class have to subcribe to its own PropertyChanged  event, which i don't like

Comment: True, there has been a post on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031157/is-it-poor-form-for-a-c-sharp-class-to-subscribe-to-its-own-published-events

Comment: I would prefer the second method as well. Seems to me the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider running some code in the 'set' of the other properties:

```
private int a;
public int A
{
    get { return a; }
    set
    {
        a= value;
        D = A + B + C
    }
}
```

You can decide for yourself if you think this is more elegant, just a suggestion.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution because there are multiple dependencies. Doing the calculations in the get accessor for D is probably a better approach than this.

Comment: I agree, see my comment in Juan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize the [ReactiveUI Observable As Property Helper](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper/) like the following:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private int a = 2;
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref a, value); }
    }

    private int b = -1;
    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref b, value); }
    }

    private int c = 5;
    public int C
    {
        get { return c; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref c, value); }
    }

    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> dHelper;
    public int D => dHelper.Value;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        dHelper = this.WhenAnyValue(
            vm => vm.a,
            vm => vm.b,
            vm => vm.c,
            (a, b, c) => a + b + c)
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(D));
    }
}
```